# while... cycle ends after if statement in public static method C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods, while-loop, public

I wrote some code in public static method with cycle "while". But this cycle ends after "if" statement, and application doesn't throw any exception. Here is the code:

```
public static void ShortcutDetect()
{
    ShortkeyIndex = 0;
    while(ShortkeyIndex < 1000) 
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\log.txt",
            File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\log.txt") + Convert.ToString(ShortkeyIndex));
        if(Program.key.Replace("LShiftKey","Shift")
            .Replace("RShiftKey","Shift").Replace("RMenu","Alt")
            .Replace("LMenu","Alt").Replace("RControlKey","Ctrl")
            .Replace("LControlKey","Ctrl").EndsWith(RawShortkeys[ShortkeyIndex]))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(RawShortkeys[ShortkeyIndex]);
        }
        ShortkeyIndex++;
    }
}
```

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Why would'n it end? 1000 iterations would take very short time.

Comment: how do you arrive at the conclusion that " this cycle ends after "if" statement, "? how did you test it?

Comment: Are you sure only one "cycle" is executed? Did you debug the code? From what you´ve posted there´s no indication for this.

Comment: @Guy, i really don't know. If you have noticed, i have added File.WriteAllText to log loops. And i see only 0 index in log file!

Comment: @MongZhu, I added FileWrite method, which writes checked index in log file. I recieved only 0 index instead of from 0 to 1000.

Comment: You´d better be off to open the file once *before* the loop, build your string to be written as one single string (e.g. using `StringBuilder`) and after the loop terminates write that string to the file as a whole.

Comment: Make sure the file exists in the specified path. Other than that there is no problem with your code.

Comment: @HimBromBeere thank you very much, but my goal isn't write text to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just implement it right:

```
public static void ShortcutDetect() {
  // Take loop independent code out of the loop:
  // and, please, format it out:
  var source = Program.key
    .Replace("LShiftKey", "Shift")
    .Replace("RShiftKey", "Shift")
    .Replace("RMenu", "Alt")
    .Replace("LMenu", "Alt")
    .Replace("RControlKey", "Ctrl")
    .Replace("LControlKey", "Ctrl");

  // Wrong type of loop (while): what is ShortkeyIndex?
  // where has it been declared, why 1000?
  // Please, have a look how the right loop easy to implement and read   
  foreach (var item in RawShortkeys) {
    // Debug: let's output item onto Console
    // Console.WriteLine(item);
    // Debug: ...or in the file
    // File.AppendAllText()@"C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\log.txt", " " + item); 

    if (source.EndsWith(item)) // <- put a break point here, inspect item's
      MessageBox.Show(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I discovered that my application stops at .EndsWith(), if this method checks RawShortkeys[ShortkeyIndex].

Comment: @SOCIOPATH: you have several problems with your current loop: it's totally unclear what is `ShortkeyIndex` and where it's been declared; what is `1000` (magic number) how it correlates to `RawShortkeys` collections; why `while` loop when you actually want `foreach` one